# Change content of IE9 about:tabs

Tags: tabs, internet-explorer-9

I want to change the location of the about:tabs to my 3x3links.com page. I am aware that you can set the default behavior to automatically load your first homepage as the new tab. This is not what I want. I want my homepage to remain (just one) and my new tab to be a total different URL.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one Crasy way, **for IE8 only** , using the registry

Go to this location.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs
```

In the registry and Export that entire AboutURLs section, so you have a backup, or have a full disk backup, or write everything down you change.  there is no UNDO button in the regedit :-)

Now just go to the TABS string in there, and doubble click on it, and change it to a web sites complete address.

I have no idea of what the ramifications of this are, I tested it, and  it works, but oddly, and may need some refinements.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have a TABS value under that Key on Windows 7

Comment: oh great, because I tested it in IE8, I will switch to IE9 and see if it is changed.

Comment: @jonathan To tuff for me, the above does not exist in IE9, and it also will not damage IE9 or effect upgrading. . .  IE9 uses a different method , and I attempted hacks of some things , like the IEframe.dll and didnt get anywhere yet. so whomever voted that up can now vote it down. I might try again , but it has me whooped for now.